# Nested firebase.database function not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My nested firebase.database query returns an:

```
[DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).
    at error (/user_code/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:40:21)
    at app (/user_code/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:297:13)
    at Object.serviceNamespace [as database] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/index.node.cjs.js:355:47)
    at exports.watchUpdates.functions.database.ref.onCreate (/user_code/index.js:18:14)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:120:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:151:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:827:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

Code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const firebase = require('firebase');

exports.watchUpdates = functions.database
  .ref('/logs/{teamName}/session/logArchive/{id}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

    //console.log(snapshot.val())

    firebase.database()
      .ref('/logs/{teamName}/session/statistic')
      .once('value')
      .then((statisticSnapshot) => {
      console.log(statisticSnapshot.val());
      if (statisticSnapshot.exists()) {
        let newLog = snapshot.val();
        let statistic = statisticSnapshot.val();
        let totalParticipators = statistic.totalParticipation;
        let averageEnergy = statistic.averageEnergy * totalParticipators;
        let averageEnjoyment = statistic.averageEnjoyment * totalParticipators;
        let newParticipator = totalParticipators + 1;
        let newAverageEnergy = (averageEnergy + newLog.energy) / newParticipator;
        let newAverageEnjoyment = (averageEnjoyment + newLog.enjoyment) / newParticipator;
        let newAverage = (newAverageEnergy + newAverageEnjoyment) / 2;
        let statisticTotalMembers = statistic.totalMembers;
        let participationRate = (newParticipator * 100) / statisticTotalMembers;
        let newStatisticObject = {
          totalMembers: statisticTotalMembers,
          participationRate: participationRate,
          averageEnergy: newAverageEnergy,
          averageEnjoyment: newAverageEnjoyment,
          averageStat: newAverage,
          totalParticipation: newParticipator,
        };
        return firebase.database()
          .ref('/logs/{teamName}/session/statistic')
          .set(newStatisticObject)
      }
    })
  });
```

The commented out `//console.log(snapshot.val();` works as i want it to but trying to go deeper results in errors.

`firebase.admin.database()` - did not fix the issue and further attempts with .admin also didn't work.

the no `$` on `{teamName}` is intentional don't think there is an issue there.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `return` before the internal `firebase.database()` call? Without doing so, the function is returning immediately and so the async call to fetch data likely isn't working.

Comment: Added the answer. If i have time i'll try doing it with your method.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by doing:

```
    snapshot.ref.parent.parent.child('statistic')
      .once('value')
      .then((statisticSnapshot) => {
      console.log(statisticSnapshot.val())
});
```

instead of:

```
    firebase.database()
      .ref('/logs/{teamName}/session/statistic')
      .once('value')
      .then((statisticSnapshot) => {
      console.log(statisticSnapshot.val());
```